# Missing $ Inserted After Index

Tags: indexing, imakeidx

I am typing some notes.  I ran "makeindex" on my two indices.  I PDFLaTeX'd the notes and all was well.  Then I added the hyperref package.  I then ran "makeindex" to generate my indices by doing "makeindex index.idx" and "makeindex notation.idx"  Now when I PDFLaTeX it gives me an error of "missing $ inserted".  The notes are separated into sections, each section with its own TeX file.  The error says it occurs on line 5, which in my main file is \usepackage{setspace}.  What might be causing this?

EDIT: Here are some things from my .log file.  I have omitted errors that I feel are not needed.  The line the error from [4] references is a section title that use $'s to achieve math mode.

```
[4]
("C:\Users\jjohnson\Dropbox\Jolie\Joe Teaching\Linear Algebra\Spring 2014\Notes
\section12.tex"

Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (PDFDocEncoding):
(hyperref)                removing `math shift' on input line 1.


Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (PDFDocEncoding):
(hyperref)                removing `superscript' on input line 1.


Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (PDFDocEncoding):
(hyperref)                removing `math shift' on input line 1.




[22]
("C:\Users\jjohnson\Dropbox\Jolie\Joe Teaching\Linear Algebra\Spring 2014\Notes
\notation.ind"
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
            $
l.5 

I've inserted a begin-math/end-math symbol since I think
you left one out. Proceed, with fingers crossed.
```

Comment: Did you check all index entries to look for some missing `$`.

Comment: @Sigur I just went back and checked.  No '$' seems to be missing.  As I said, I have generated the PDF at least two or three times without error.  I only started getting the error after I added the hyperref package.

Comment: Line 5 can refer to a different file; if you know how to run `pdflatex` from a terminal window, calling it `pdflatex -file-line-error` followed by the file name should make it clear what file it refers to.

Comment: check the output: the erroneous `$` will put the text into math mode. (My guess is an errant `_` somewhere.)

Comment: @egreg I ran it in terminal and it told me that the line where the error occurs is where I have \usepackage{setspace}.  I tried to comment out the package and it still says there is an error on that line.

Comment: @JoeJohnson126 Please, report the entire error message you find in the `.log` file

Comment: @egreg I have included some errors from the .log file.

Comment: @JoeJohnson126 It's line 5 in `notation.ind`, probably a faulty index entry.

Comment: @egreg That allowed me to figure out the problem.  If you list what you told me as an answer, I can upvote it and give you credit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to cope with these error messages is, first of all, looking at the log file and not simply at the short messages given by front ends.

If possible, launch the LaTeX run (whatever engine) with the `-file-line-error` that will better inform about what file is involved in the error. In any case, a file that's input is reported in the log file with an open parenthesis followed by the file name; in some cases it might be difficult to find it, with the `-file-line-error` option activated, the `l. 5` indicator (of line 5 in the currently input file) is substituted by `<filename>:<line number>`.

Your log file tells us that the error is in `notation.ind`, at line 5; this is a file produced by MakeIndex. The probable cause is a malformed index entry.

How to activate the `-file-line-error` option? This could be recommended in all cases, by the way. If the TeX distribution is MiKTeX, the name of the option could be different, check the documentation.

### TeXworks

Go to the Preferences, Typesetting tab and edit the `pdflatex` tool according to the following picture

[image]

Click OK twice and you're done.

### TeXStudio (formerly TeXMakerX)

Go to the Preferences, Commands tab; add `-file-line-error` to the build commands; in the picture I added it to `pdflatex`. The path to the binaries could be different, but the general flavor should be the same.

[image]

Comment: (Enrico): Would it be possible for you to make a separate page that explains this procedure step-by-step please (or even edit your answer)? It would be really helpful for all self-learners. Eg. how to launch latex run you mention initially, which file you exactly refer to etc...Grazie mile

Comment: @AbhimanyuArora How to add the option depends on what method you use to launch the LaTeX run; there are really many possibilities. Can you tell what method you're using?

Comment: @Enrico: Well, I just open the shortcut to my editor to run latex. I use three editors: TeXWorks/TeXniCentre/TexMakerX. Hope that is what you ask?

Comment: @AbhimanyuArora I added the procedure for TeXworks and TeXStudio. I'm afraid I can't do it for TeXnicCenter, as I am a proud nonowner of machines running Windows. `;-)`

Comment: @Enrico: Grazie mile, miofratello :-), you are very kind